# stripe Prebuilt Checkout page with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Hi I am using Laravel and based on documentation of stripe for PHP: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder I have added following to code to test whether it works or not and this is not workig for me. As the per demo I need to redirect to the stripe checkout form and this is not happening. When user submit the button I want to redirect to stripe form with product details

step 1: `composer require stripe/stripe-php`

step 2: My home.blade.php copied from docs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buy cool new product</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="product">
        <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
          alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"

        />
        <div class="description">

          <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
          <h5>.00</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">@csrf
        <button type="submit" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

and step 3

```
Route::post('/create-checkout-session',function(){
  

   // require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_FfKP0notiUK0s5XOrs7O3MKR');
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    $YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:8000';
    
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
      'line_items' => [[
        # TODO: replace this with the `price` of the product you want to sell
        'price' => 'price_1RaJ35tHwG6zssijf9MneD9SQ',
        'quantity' => 1,
      ]],
      'payment_method_types' => [
        'card',
      ],
      'mode' => 'payment',
      'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
      'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
    ]);
    
    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
});
```

Comment: What's the error you're facing?

Comment: i am not getting any error.I am redirected to this url localhost:8000/create-checkout-session, but not to the stripe.com

Comment: Check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#payment-methods-for-single-charges

Comment: i want to checkout through stripe form

Comment: When user submit the button, they will go to your server (localhost:8000/create-checkout-session) first, then be redirected to Stripe Checkout URL. So it’s correct to be in localhost:8000/create-checkout-session like you observed, but for some reason the next redirection logic is not performed.

Is there any log on your server log? Have you tried to put some debug in your server code? Like have you actually created the Checkout Session? Or you have created it and instructed client to redirect, but client failed due to some error in Console log?

Answer (score 0):

One common reason for this issue is that the frontend is sending the POST request to the incorrect URL.

Right now your form is using a relative URL — the data is sent to a different URL on the same origin i.e. http://localhost:8000/create-checkout-session.

You should verify what is the domain and port that your server is listening on and either :

Edit your frontend code to specify the correct domain and port in an absolute URL in the action attribute.

Example

```
<form action="http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
```

OR

Setup a proxy to the correct domain and port for any unknown requests to your API server in development. If you're using React - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/